# Using colorbox with URL's \path command

Tags: macros, xetex, color, line-breaking, urls

I am trying to print URL and other paths within a gray-colored box. However, I cannot do so. The moment I use `\colorbox` with `\path`, the line breaking stops working. It appears as if `\colorbox` stops `\path` from breaking lines; `\color` doesn't.

Is there a way to rectify it?

I tried reading through `url.sty` but my limited understanding of LaTeX could not decipher it. I tried going through the definitions of `\path` and `\colorbox`. Didn't understand it much though.

```
\path:
macro:->\leavevmode \begingroup \urlstyle {tt}\Url 


\colorbox:
macro:#1{->\protect \color@box {#1}{

\color@box {#1}{:
undefined
```

Here are two related (maybe) but different questions

1. [file ended while scanning use of \path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315673/file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-path)
2. [Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself)

Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{xcolor}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\LetLtxMacro{\oldpath}{\path}
\renewcommand{\path}[1]{{\colorbox{gray!8}{\oldpath{#1}}}}

\newrobustcmd\pathcb[1]{\colorbox{gray!8}{\path{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\colorbox{gray!7}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\strut \path{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77877/line-break-inside-a-verbhttps://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77877/line-break-inside-a-verb}\strut}}

\pathcb{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77877/line-break-inside-a-verbhttps://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77877/line-break-inside-a-verb}

\path{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77877/line-break-inside-a-verbhttps://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77877/line-break-inside-a-verb}

\end{document}
```

I tried [Werner's answer to breakable colorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310370/95405) but the lines still won't break. I'd rather avoid TiKz, having absolutely no knowledge about it.

Do let me know if I can provide more details.

Comment: Well colorbox won't break across lines, and putting url's and pathes (which can contains specials chars like `~`  or `%`)  in the argument of some other command is normally not a good idea, if the command is not specially meant for verbatim material. Imho your best bet to get something working is tikzmarks at the begin and the end. But before trying to get something working: background color is a rather  brutal method to emphasize. Do you really think it is a good idea to use it in running text?

Comment: Many websites display console commands and paths in a fixed width font and background color to emphasise it. Like so - `I am a path`. I was hoping to borrow this style

Comment: websites are different to printed text. When a link is hidden behind some text ("I am a link") you need to indicate that there is a link, but if the text is "http://www..." why emphasise? And looking at how tex.sx shows your question: The colored links are okay, the gray code block too, but the background color of the commands disrupts my reading. I would prefer here a tt-font with perhaps a bit color.

Answer (score 1):

Commands such as `\url` and `\path` *don't* absorb their argument, but delay doing so in order to make several settings in between.

Add the color as a font attribute:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto{\UrlFont}{\color{gray!70}}

\begin{document}

Some text for triggering a line break
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77877/line-break-inside-a-verb}
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77877/line-break-inside-a-verb}
and some text after the links

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I have to write a macro, which prints backslashes and all other special characters just like `\path`, but is in a colorbox and line-breaks appropriately (like a path)?

Comment: @manucpp Isn't it the same?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I had `\url{}` in my mind all this while. I will delete that comment.